# Basic network simulation with VirtualBox Images

Tags: networking, network-programming, virtualbox, virtual, virtualization

to test a project I'm developing for my bachelor thesis I need a basic network setup (a few subnets, routers...). I've tried to create a virtual network with the VirtualBox Images I have to use but I'm struggling quite a bit here since the beginning of the week. Do you have any recommendations for a network virtualization/simulation software that allows using custom VirtualBox Images for the hosts and is easy to use? I looked into GNS3, Emulab and others but I'm not quite sure which software is the best one to use here. Sorry if it seems I did not invest much time but the actual practical testing of my project is just a small part. It would even suffice to have two subnets with one router in between although scalability would be neat.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> basic network setup (a few sub nets, routers...)

for this propose you can simply use [Cisco Packet Tracer](https://www.netacad.com/courses/packet-tracer-download/) for test network setup or education proposes, you can check the website for more information.

> using custom VirtualBox Images

Cisco Packet Tracer network gives you network adapter config and shell command and basic networking tools on your hosts to test your network but if you need your custom OS images to be hosted in the network virtualization/simulation software you better look at this article that 
[How to emulate a network using VirtualBox](http://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-use-virtualbox-to-emulate-a-network/).

Comment: I worked through the exact same article but a lot of the stuff from there is not working for me. I was hoping for a simple solution where I can just deploy my VMs without configuring each hosts separately.

Comment: There is almost no simple alternative way for applying network configuration in your case than configuring separately each host, but it wouldn't be much complicated if you explain more about configuration.